# Swiftui - How to Timer.scheduledTimer apply to make UiView every n second

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiview

I am new to swiftUI to make view as like what I done in UIkit. tried almost few hours did not get success.

here is my code in UIkit which is working good in my project.

```
  var positionY = self.view.frame.height
     let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 3.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
           // do stuff 3 seconds later
         positionY = positionY - 50
        let bubble = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.frame.width/2, y:  positionY, width: 50, height: 50))
        bubble.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(bubble)
       
      }
    
    RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .common)
```

now I am working on SwifUI. I need same behaviour on my swiftUI project because of I have done lot of stuff on this  code.

Answer (score 2):

Customize it as per your requirement:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var positionYOffset: CGFloat = 0
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 3, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                .position(x: geometry.size.width/2, y: geometry.size.height - positionYOffset)
        }.onReceive(timer) { _ in
           positionYOffset += 50
        }
    }
}
```